# Recalcular formula

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy usando la librería `PHPExcel`, y tengo el problema que cuando cambio los valores de dos celdas, las formulas que tengo que incluyen a esa celdas, no reflejan el cambio; es decir, las formulas no se recalculan.

Este es el código:

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    $archivo = "PHPExcel/excel/axa.xlsx";

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
    $sheet1 = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 

    //MUESTRO LOS VALORES ACTUALES
    echo $sheet1->getCell("R22")->getValue() . "<br>";
    echo $sheet1->getCell("R24")->getValue() . "<br>";
    echo $sheet1->getCell("R38")->getCalculatedValue() . "<br>";


    echo "VALORES CAMBIADOS <br>";
    $sheet1->setCellValue('R22', 7550000000);
    $sheet1->setCellValue('R24', 12000000000);
    echo $sheet1->getCell("R22")->getValue() . "<br>"; //AQUI MUESTRO NUEVAMENTE LAS CELDAS Y ME APARECE EL CAMBIO
    echo $sheet1->getCell("R24")->getValue() . "<br>";

    echo $sheet1->getCell("R38")->getCalculatedValue() . "<br>"; //ESTA ES LA CELDA CON LA FORMULA QUE NO REFLEJA EL CAMBIO
```

Answer (score 1):

`PHPExcel` guarda el resultado del cálculo en caché y esto no se borra cuando se modifica el valor de las celdas relacionadas.

#### Solución:

El cache puede ser borrado utilizado:

```
// Vaciar el caché de cálculo para cualquier instancia existente
PHPExcel_Calculation::flushInstance();

// o

// Vaciar el caché de cálculo solo de la instancia
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->clearCalculationCache();

// o

// Vaciar el caché de cálculo solo de la worksheet indicada
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->clearCalculationCacheForWorksheet($worksheetName);
```

También puede deshabilitar el almacenamiento en caché de cálculos por completo (*aunque esto puede ralentizar las cosas si tiene muchas fórmulas que hacen referencia a celdas que contienen otras fórmulas*), antes de comenzar a procesar sus archivos, usando:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->setCalculationCacheEnabled(false);
```

---

#### Créditos:

[Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9142966/3791844)